# Duplicate custom object copying it by value not by reference

Tags: swift

Which is the correct way to duplicate an object in swift 3?

I have an object

```
var element: Element!
```

Element is an ObjectMapper class

```
class Element: Mappable {

    var name = String()
    var description = String()
    var price = Float()
    var optionals = [Optional]()

    required init?(map: Map){
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        name            <- map["n"]
        description     <- map["d"]
        price           <- map["p"]
        optionals       <- map["o"]
    }

}
```

I want to initialize *element* with some object of type **Element** and then create a *tmpElement* copied from *element* to modify *tmpElement* and leave *element* "untouched".

If I do

```
tmpElement = element
```

I think I am passing the reference so what I modify in tmpElement it will be modified in element too.

So which is the right way? I hope I explained myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an `init`ializer that takes the `Element` to copy as an argument:

```
...
init(element:Element) {
     name = element.name
     description = element.description
     price = element.price
     optionals = element.optionals
}
...
```

and use it like this:

```
let element = Element(map)
let copy = Element(element)
```

Alternatively you could make `Element` a `struct` instead of a `class`.

Comment: Ok, I made all my Mappable´s classes as structs... there will be an impact in the memoy usage now?

Comment: You can find detailed information regarding classes and struct [in the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html). Or google for "copy on write" and "value and reference types" for Swift to get a better understanding